# A field with irreducible polynomial that has multiple roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Can you give me an example of a field $\mathbb{K}$ such that there exists a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ that is irreducible and has a multiple root?

Comment: You can find an answer to your question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106632/examples-of-fields-which-are-not-perfect

Answer (score 5):

Hint: the characteristic of $K$ can't be $0$; and $K$ must be infinite. Can you think to an infinite field of characteristic $2$ and to a degree two irreducible polynomial having multiple root?