# Show that the polynomial $x^2 − t \in F[x]$ is irreducible over $F$, but that it has a multiple root in some extension field of $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $\mathbb{Z}_2[t]$ be a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}_2 $ and $F = \mathbb{Z}_2(t)$ its field of fractions.
> Show that the polynomial $x^2 − t \in F[x]$ is irreducible over $F$, but that it has a
> multiple root in some extension field of $F$. In particular, conclude that $F$ is not a
> perfect field.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164619/790670) answer shows why $x^2-t$ is irreducible over $F[x]$ using a generalization of the Eisenstein criterion. I can understand how this works, but I wonder if in this case irreducibility can be determined in some more elementary way. For example, conclude that this polynomial cannot factor as a product of lower degree polynomials (?)

For the second part of the exercise, if $a$ is a root of $x^2-t$ in a splitting field $K$ of $F$. Note that $a^2=t\in F$. So $x^2-t=x^2-a^2=(x-a)^2\in F[x]\subset K[x]$. Thus, $a$ is a multiple root of $x^2-t$ in $K$, and hence $F$ is not a perfect field. In this part, Am I right?

The definition of perfect field in my book is

> A field $F$ is said to be perfect if no irreducible $f (x) \in F[x]$ has
> multiple roots in any splitting field of $f (x)$ over $F$

And the definition of multiple root is

> Let $F$ be a field, $f (x) \in F[x]$ and $a \in F$. We say that $a$ is a
> multiple root of $f (x)$ if $(x − a)^2\mid f (x)$

Comment: What is $t$????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, there is indeed an elementary way: if $X^2-T$ is not irreducible, it factors as the product of two monic linear (in $X$) polynomials, and hence it has a root in $\mathbf F_2[T]$. However, this is impossible for degree reasons.

For your second question, your argument is correct.

Note that the extension in which the polynomial $X^2-T$ splits into linear factors is (isomorphic to) the field
$$\mathbf F_2(T)[X]/(X^2-T),$$
in which the root is the congruence class $\xi$ of $X\bmod X^2-T$.

Comment: I can understand why it should have such factorization, but the impossibility of the root is not clear to me (when you say "this is impossible for degree reasons"). Could you please explain to me why this happens.

Comment: @Hopmaths: you would have a non-constant polynomial $p(T)$ such that $\;\bigl(p(T)\bigr)^2=T$. It is not possible, since the degree of the l.h.s. is even, $\ge 2$, whereas the r.h.s.  has degree $1$.