# Example of a field of characteristic p in which the Frobenius endomorphism fails to be surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Then the $p$-th power map, $x\mapsto x^p$ is called the Frobenius endomorphism. If $F$ is a finite field, this is an automorphism. Injectivity of this map is guaranteed since it is a field homomorphism. What is an example of an infinite field in which this map fails to be surjective?

Comment: Look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106632/examples-of-fields-which-are-not-perfect . That's an example of a non-perfect field and thus the Frobenius map isn't an automorphism.

Answer (score 2):

$F = \mathbb F_p(t)$.

In slightly more detail, suppose that $f \in \mathbb F_p(t)$ is a rational function of $t$ over $\mathbb F_p$ whose image under the Frobenius is $t$. Write $f(t) = \frac {P(t)} {Q(t)}$ for polynomials $P$, $Q$ over $\mathbb F_p$. Then $f(t)^p = \frac {P(t)^p} {Q(t)^p} = t$, so $P(t)^p = Q(t)^p t$. Taking degrees gives $p \deg P = p \deg Q + 1$ and so $p \cdot (\deg P - \deg Q) = 1$, which is impossible since $p$ divides the left-hand side but not the right. Therefore the Frobenius is not surjective.